# What do you call the impressive short sentences catalogs and magazine use to write product descriptions?

Tags: sentence, abbreviations

A couple of years ago I heard a word descriptive of short and impressive sentences that are used in catalogs and websites for product descriptions.
I don't remember that specific word. Do you have any idea what it might be?

I need it for use in place of the words *short description*.

Comment: Spicy bears? (No, probably not.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Blurb" is the generic for this sort of item. "Catch copy" is also commonly used.

Comment: I was gonna answer "blurb" but you beat me to it.

Comment: A "blurb" would be found on a book jacket or in promo material for books. It's o.k. to extend this to a short product description, as you did. I would prefer "specifications", "product summary" or "capsule information", myself. For a product webpage with clickable tabs, such as "Purchase", "Comments", "Photo", you could put "Specs" on the tab.

Answer (score 5):

Slogan?  Sound bite?  Unique selling proposition?  Marketing tripe?

Synopsis?  Summary?

Comment: i think it was more specific -it used in literature. not one of them, but you gave me an idea. thank you john

Comment: Added a couple more (synopsis, summary)

Comment: first four much closer

Comment: I like "Marketing tripe"!  Far too much of it around.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're looking for:

> Catch phrase

Comment: can i use this one 'catch phrase' instead of **short description**

Comment: By the way, *catchphrase* is one word. And I don't think it's apt for this context.

Comment: Take that back! It certainly could be apt for this!

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catchphrase it's fine either way. @dino beytar, it's dangerous to answer a question like "can I use this word in place of this other word" because it's so important to look at the context. I would suggest editing your question to include a sentence you wish to use it in.

Answer (score 4):

[Elevator pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch):

> An elevator pitch summary used to quickly and simply define a product, service, or organization and its value proposition. The name "elevator pitch" reflects the idea that it should be possible to deliver the summary in the time span of an elevator ride, or approximately thirty seconds to two minutes.

Usage: *Give me the short (and sweet) version of why I would want this*.

Comment: it's really interesting one -i didn't looking for this, but i'm gonna thinking about it.

Comment: Have a google. It is used a LOT. Like "What is the elevator pitch for Agile" as in _give me the short version of why I would want this_ - hey that is one too

Answer (score 2):

The word you may be looking for is *byword*, which in this context would be defined as:

> a word or expression summarizing a thing's characteristics or a person's principles
>
> <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/byword)</sup>

Another, slightly less formal, option is *tag line*:

> a catchphrase or slogan, especially as used in advertising, or the punchline of a joke
>
> <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tag_line)</sup>

Comment: i am sure that not both of them. that word should be used instead of short description. thank you

Comment: @dino: What about *epithet*? More formal, but is that what you are looking for?

Comment: i think we're closing, but do you prefer epithet to describe **product short describtion**.

Comment: @dino: Just to get some clarification: Are you open to just any word or are you trying to remember a word you once heard? *Epithet* is certainly not a great choice for the specific case you mention. I only threw it out there, as I thought you were trying to zone in on a particular word you heard before.

Comment: exactly i am trying to remember that word -not new one.

Answer (score 0):

**Motto** is what you are looking for:

> a sentence, phrase, or word inscribed on something as appropriate to or indicative of its character or use

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motto)